# How to install charlock_holmes dependency libicu-dev on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, icu

I'm using the ruby gem [charlock_holmes](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) in a Rails 4 app to detect the character encodings of CSV's that I'm parsing so that `CSV.foreach` doesn't throw an error.

However, when I try to push to heroku (with `gem 'charlock_holmes'` in the Gemfile) I get the following error:

```
Installing charlock_holmes (0.6.9.4)
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   /tmp/build_e741f6ed-a860-47bf-8c0d-1b678fa0ebeb/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for main() in -licui18n... no
   checking for main() in -licui18n... no


   ***************************************************************************************
   *********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
   ***************************************************************************************
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
   need configuration options.

   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/tmp/build_e741f6ed-a860-47bf-8c0d-1b678fa0ebeb/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
   --with-icu-dir
   --without-icu-dir
   --with-icu-include
   --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
   --with-icu-lib
   --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/
   --with-icui18nlib
   --without-icui18nlib
   --with-icui18nlib
   --without-icui18nlib


   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_e741f6ed-a860-47bf-8c0d-1b678fa0ebeb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_e741f6ed-a860-47bf-8c0d-1b678fa0ebeb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing charlock_holmes (0.6.9.4), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4'` succeeds before
   bundling.
```

**How do I get `libicu-dev` to install on Heroku?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the other two solutions don't work for me (see below), so I had to come up with my own solution. This solution works with Ruby 1.9.3 but [hammady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441849/hammady) says it does not work with 2.0.0.

I used `heroku-buildpack-multi`:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

With the following `.buildpacks`:

```
https://github.com/benjie/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

And this `Aptfile`:

```
libicu-dev
```

[My fork](https://github.com/benjie/heroku-buildpack-apt/compare/ddollar:master...master) of `heroku-buildpack-apt` is required to export the `BUNDLE_BUILD__CHARLOCK_HOLMES` variable via [Heroku's ENV_DIRs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-compile). In the Gemfile you just reference `gem 'charlock_holmes'` as usual and all works smoothly now for me.

If anyone can think of a way that doesn't involve exporting `BUNDLE_BUILD__CHARLOCK_HOLMES` then please let me know!

---

[Ryan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819175/ryan-linton) answer doesn't work for me - Heroku bails because the bundle install step doesn't offer any output for 3 minutes. [Silasj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371381/silasj) answer references the `frederick/heroku-buildpack-ruby` buildpack which is no longer maintained and lags behind the official `heroku-buildpack-ruby` by quite an amount, which is not acceptable to me.

Comment: I am very fortunate to have find your answer only after 18 hours after posting it! I am pushing now and will see if it works :)

Comment: It didn't work for me. Here is the output from git push: http://pastebin.com/W7izp3fD, I also tried heroku build as stated in https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt but fails with readonly file system, output here: http://pastebin.com/TwFtwmvG. It is weird that I can see libicu installed but bundler still can't build native extension.

Comment: @hammady I'd be very interested to know if you figure out what went wrong; it's worked for me for a few pushes now but I spent over 4 hours yesterday iterating to get to that point. I think your `heroku build` command is failing because of the new [ENV_DIR](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-compile) stuff - the compile script doesn't seem to be sent a `$3` so it's trying to write to `/LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `/path/to/ENV_DIR/LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @hammady I've just pushed out a new version of heroku-buildpack-apt that exports a few more variables to the ENV_DIR and fixes an issue I didn't realise I had relating to running `rake` during the push. Other than that I'm at a loss; though you're using Ruby 2 whilst I'm on 1.9.3.

Comment: yes the Ruby 2 was the culprit! Specifying ruby '1.9.3' in the Gemfile fixed it! I wonder why would ruby 2 fail to find the native libraries: /tmp/build_a46064ac-89bf-4503-9fe1-28bc880896dd/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-icu-dir="/tmp/build_a46064ac-89bf-4503-9fe1-28bc880896dd/.apt/usr"
       checking for main() in -licui18n... no
       checking for main() in -licui18n... no

Comment: Thanks your solution gave me everything I needed to get this working - I've changed the process slightly to use a specific .bundle/config for heroku with a third build pack. Details here: http://tooky.co.uk/using-charklock_holmes-on-heroku/

Answer (score 13):

Try using `gem "charlock_holmes_bundle_icu", "~> 0.6.9.2"`. [More info.](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/pull/4)

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I'll try this and see how it goes.

Comment: That worked. I didn't specify the version, though, as I'm using this in a Rails Engine.

Comment: Worked for me! FYI - after using this solution, I had to include `require 'charlock_holmes'` at the top of any file I used Charlock holmes.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT June 2017:** As custom one-off buildpacks for this singular issue seem to go out of date, I'd recommend trying the approach presented by Benjie in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662875/1371381). Use heroku-buildpack-multi and [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) with an `Aptfile` to specify dependencies.

Steve Tooke also has an excellent write-up on this very issue: http://tooky.co.uk/using-charklock_holmes-on-heroku/ -- note that things may have changed in the 3 years since this question was asked, but the thing to remember is that generic/supported, rather than specific/unsupported, is the best route to go with buildpacks.

**Original Answer:**

While [Ryan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819175/ryan-linton) answer works, it also slows down deploy times to -in my tests- up to 15 minutes. I even ran into Heroku's deploy time limit a few times.

An easier solution (that doesn't affect deploy times), is to use a Heroku [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

[Aaron Severs](https://github.com/webandtech) created a buildpack that includes icu4c (which `charlock_holmes` relies on) in the dyno build. [[see here]](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/49#issuecomment-29689571)

Steps to make it work (Copied from Aaron's comment for posterity):

1. Install the buildpack CLI:
   `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpacks`
2. Set the buildpack to Aaron's fork `heroku buildpacks:set frederick/heroku-buildpack-ruby -a myapp`
3. In your Gemfile, use: `gem 'charlock_holmes'`

Comment: This is still a valid answer, and while Benjie says the `frederick/heroku-buildpack-ruby` is not maintained, it was recently updated and seem to be continously updated - at least when I checked the README.md last.

Comment: I get `remote:  !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack` when doing these steps. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

This works:

Execute the following commands and install this:

1. brew install erlang icu4c spidermonkey

2. brew ln icu4c


This will install the required dependencies and then try to install charlock_homes.

Comment: The OP is able to install locally but is having difficulty getting to install on heroku. This answer doesn't address OP's question (which is why it's been downvoted).