# How to install libmagic on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, apt-get, libmagic

I have a rails 4 app that uses `ruby-filemagic`, and so `filemagic` needs to be installed on the system.

I've tried installing it on Heroku by mimicing solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926574/how-to-install-charlock-holmes-dependency-libicu-dev-on-heroku), but it just won't work. I've tried multiple things, but the one I think is the most promising is installing via `apt-get` thanks to a combination of the (modified) [apt-get](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt), [config](https://github.com/timolehto/heroku-bundle-config) and [ruby](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) buildpacks.
In the config, I use `BUNDLE_BUILD__RUBY-FILEMAGIC: --with-magic-dir=/app/.apt/usr/ --with-magic-include=/app/.apt/usr/include --with-magic-lib=/app/.apt/usr/lib`

Eventually, I still get this:

```
  /tmp/build_29e629f8a00379850ab44096c10f1afc/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-magic-dir=/tmp/build_29e629f8a00379850ab44096c10f1afc/.apt/usr/ --with-magic-include=/tmp/build_29e629f8a00379850ab44096c10f1afc/.apt/usr/include --with-magic-lib=/tmp/build_29e629f8a`00379850ab44096c10f1afc/.apt/usr/lib
   checking for main() in -lgnurx... no
   checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no
   *** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
   need configuration options.
```

`libmagic` did get installed into this directory. Its contents are equivalent to the contents of the `deb` package, although it does seem quite light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working:

.buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt#master
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#master
```

Aptfile:

```
libmagic-dev
```

The heroku-bundle-config was not necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me on a fresh Heroku install, same error as OP

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `heroku-buildpack-magic` buildpack before the main buildpack

`heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/NetsoftHoldings/heroku-buildpack-magic.git`